# Make this animation in flutter for a checkbox or Text category Row

Tags: list, flutter, animation, dart, checkbox

Im looking this animation for Flutter, does anyone know if is this possible?

since im making an app that needs to check if all the categories are checked by the user, if not when press the button it should mark the ones that arent checked actually,

Im giving a short video of Oneplus 8 pro device that makes the animation that im looking for

if is not already done by a widget or something at least to have a name of how this animation is called would be really appretiated.

here is a gif example:

https://gfycat.com/similarbonyeyra

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the whole code to animate like that. Of course you can tweak it according to your choice..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyBlinkingButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyBlinkingButtonState createState() => _MyBlinkingButtonState();
}

class _MyBlinkingButtonState extends State<MyBlinkingButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> animation;
  int count = 1;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = new AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(_animationController)
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          if (count < 3) _animationController.reverse();
        } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          _animationController.forward();
          count++;
        }
      })
      ..addStatusListener((state) => print('$state'));
    _animationController.forward();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: _animationController,
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState((){
          count = 0;
          _animationController.reset();
          _animationController.forward();});
        },
        child: Text("Text button"),
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Material(
        child: Center(
          child: MyBlinkingButton(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @towhid thats exactly what i was looking for!